# Added field to Phoenix form + database. Doesn't display in show.html.eex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my show.html.eex I have the following code:

```
<h1 class="display-post-title-index-show">
       <%= @post.title %>
    </h1>
       <p class="display-post-body-show">
       <%= @post.body %>
    </p>
```

It displays those fields ok on the development server.

I added 3 more fields to post.ex:

```
field :plan, :string
field :done_so_far, :string
field :project_pic, :string
```

Ran:   `mix ecto gen.migration add_plan_to_posts`

Added three string fields:

```
 def change do
     alter table(:stories_posts) do
     add :plan, :string
     add :done_so_far, :string
     add :project_pic, :string
     #timestamps
  end
```

I ran mix ecto.migrate create etc. Successful migration. 
Then  `mix run priv/repo/seeds.exs`

Added

```
 <p class="display-post-body-show">
       <%= @post.plan %>
    </p>
```

to show.html.eex, but it doesn't show upon reloading.

EDIT:

```
LiveStory.Repo.all LiveStory.Stories.Post
```

returns:

```
[%LiveStory.Stories.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "stories_posts">,
  body: "Dummy summary",
  comments: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :comments is not loaded>,
  done_so_far: nil, id: 1, inserted_at: ~N[2017-07-17 14:40:18.186146],
  modified_by: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :modified_by is not loaded>,
  modified_by_id: nil,
  original_post: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :original_post is not loaded>,
  original_post_id: nil, path: "1", plan: nil, project_pic: nil,
  published: true, removed_by_moderator: false, removed_by_owner: false,
  title: "Dummy Title",
  topic: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :topic is not loaded>,
  topic_id: 1, updated_at: ~N[2017-07-17 14:40:18.186157],
  upvotes_count: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :upvotes_count is not loaded>,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 1}]
```

Only the :body and :title fields are showing stored data. :plan is not present in the Repo readout, and :done_so_far, another field, shows no stored string. I will run migrations and seeds again.

EDIT2: Just dropped, setup and created database. Added more dummy info. Same problem.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show"? Have you added any value to the "plan" field of the post? Otherwise you'll get just `<p class="display-post-body-show"></p>` which might not be visible without inspecting the source of the page.

Comment: I mean the text I inputed doesn't display on the development server. I added some dummy text on the upload form, and it was accepted, so there's some text stored in the local database. I will inspect element, and then check the Repo to see if the text was stored.

Comment: Since the data is not in the database, did you maybe forget to add the field name in the call to `cast` in your model's `changeset` function?

Comment: That might be it. I didn't modify any code with cast. I added the fields to post.ex, and made a migration file. I'm new to this, so I could've made a simple error. What file do I need to look in, post controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably in `lib/live_story/stories/stories.ex` you have a changeset used to create your posts like so:

```
def post_changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs) do
  post
  |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body]
  ...
end
```

make sure in the `cast(attrs, [...])` function you includes your attributes `:plan, :done_so_far, :project_pic`, otherwise will not be considered when creating or updating a post.

Also, if those fields are required for each post, you add them as well in a `validate_required([...])` function in the same changeset.

Comment: I just found it, exactly as you said. Thanks for that clear explanation..

Comment: For future reference, I was using this guide:http://wsmoak.net/2015/07/27/adding-fields-to-an-ecto-model-in-phoenix.html